# Stored Procedure throwing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I tried to execute this procedure but I am getting error.

I tried to execute using:

```
execute Currentmonth 20141220
```

Error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Currentmonth, Line 15
>   Invalid object name 'DimDate'

Why I am getting this error? Can you please tell me the errors in the query for creating stored procedure and what are the parameters I am expecting?

```
create procedure Currentmonth
    @Completeddatekey varchar(20)
as
   begin
```

Getting the current date and formatting it

```
    Declare @currentdate varchar(30)
        set @currentdate = convert(Varchar(20), getdate()-1, 101)
    print @currentdate
```

Getting DayofMonth and EndofMonth from DimDate

```
     Declare @dayofmonth int
     Declare @endofmonth int

     select @dayofmonth = DayofMonth, @endofmonth = EndofMonthDateKey 
     from bi.dbo.DimDate
     where datekey = @currentdate
```

Getting HierMonthEndKey

```
     declare @hiermonthendkey int

     select @hiermonthendkey = MAX(HierMonthEndKey) 
     from DimHospiceHiearchy
     where HierMonthEndKey <= @currentdate+1

Declare @day

For Loop
     Declare @i int = 0
     declare @startdate varchar(20)
     select @startdate = CAST(CAST(YEAR(convert(Varchar(20), getdate()-1, 101)) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
     + '/' + CAST(MONTH(convert(Varchar(20), getdate()-1, 101)) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01'  AS DATETIME)+1

      While @i <=@dayofmonth
      begin
        set @startdate = @startdate+@i
        exec MA010103 @completeddatekey, @hiermonthendkey 
        set @i = @i+1
     end
   end
```

Comment: Error `Invalid object name 'DimDate'` means that you don't have table with this name.

Comment: I have a table with that name @lgor

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258716%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154056/creating-storeprocedure. IT seem you are new to sql query so i will recommened you to learn the basic of sql. http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when an object that does not exist is referenced. If the object exists, you might need to include the owner's name in the object name.

Please check the table exists in the mentioned database ?

> select @dayofmonth = DayofMonth, @endofmonth = EndofMonthDateKey from 
>   bi.dbo.DimDate
>          where datekey = @currentdate

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  Declare @dayofmonth int
 Declare @endofmonth int
 select @dayofmonth = DayofMonth, @endofmonth = EndofMonthDateKey from  bi.dbo.DimDate
   where datekey = @currentdate
```

Please try

```
  Declare @dayofmonth int
 Declare @endofmonth int
 select @dayofmonth = DayofMonth, @endofmonth = EndofMonthDateKey from  DimDate
   where datekey = @currentdate
```

Or check if DimDate Table exists